# Add 3 columns in One

Tags: sql-server, pivot, union

I'm working on this query form yesterday and I don't find any answer. I don't know how to make it.

So, I have this query with this result:

[image: Query + Result]

Code:

```
select distinct Phase as tt  from table1
      where phase is not null

select distinct [ITV en cours] as tt from table1
      where [ITV en cours] = 'OUI'

select distinct Etat as tt from table1
      where Etat like 'Ass%'
```

I want to make something like this

[image: What i want to look like]

How can I do that?

Comment: So you want all the three result sets as a single one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do either insert or union all or union to get desired result

```
select distinct Phase as tt from table1 where phase is not null
    union all
    select distinct [ITV en cours] as tt from table1 where [ITV en cours] = 'OUI'
    union all
    select distinct Etat as tt from table1 where Etat like 'Ass%'
```

Comment: god.. and i tried a lot of things.. with pivot, unpivot.. concat.. thank you very much!